# Android name in manifest file shows error

Tags: android, android-manifest

In my Android manifest file "android:name" in both the activities which I have mentioned below shows error when I tried to run the program. How can I fix this?

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity
    android:name=".ContentView"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_content_view" >
<activity>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! When you say "Unfortunately", do you mean the android "Unfortunately [app name] has stopped"? Please create a [mcve] and [edit] it into your question. With that information, maybe we can help you. The Manifest file alone is not likely to help.

Comment: does you `<manifest>` section contains `package` attribute? Activity name started with `.` is added to package name. Also if you place your activity classes under separate package (folder in navigator) you must provide its name, like `.ui.activity.Main`

Answer (score 0):

CLean Project
if it doesnt work,
remove tags and add activity again to manifest